# How could I get @FeignClient bean when spring boot application initializing

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, feign

I need use a bean inject with @Component @FeignClient(name = "xxx") when my spring boot application initializing, but it always throws exception like this:

```
20180706 10:18:40,043  WARN [main] 
[org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'feignContract' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'feignContract' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignConversionService' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'feignConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

my feignClient code:

```
@Component
@FeignClient(name = "domain-account")
public interface IDomainService {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userInfos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserInfos(@QueryMap Map<String, Object> condition);
}
```

ApplicationListenner code:

```
public class GlobalInit implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
    System.out.println("======== GlobalInit ========");
    IDomainService domainService = contextRefreshedEvent.getApplicationContext().getBean(IDomainService.class);
    System.out.println("*********************" + domainService);
    GlobalInitManager.getInstance().doInit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear for me what you try to do with the GlobalInit but the 'standard' way of designing your Feign client in Spring Boot would the following:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
@EnableCaching
public class MyHelloWorldApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
public class HelloWorldServiceImpl implements HelloWorldService {

    @Autowired
    private IDomainService iDomainService ;

    public void myMethod() {
            String userinfo = iDomainService.getUserInfos(...); 
    } 

}
```

Hopefully this helps. 
All the best, 
Wim